# how to show text and video side by side (HTML webpage)

Tags: html

I have created an HTML page with some text on left and an embedded youtube video on the right.

But the video is stretching in the height.

This is the code I am using

```html
<br>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3> <strong> Heading </strong > </h3>

<hr>

<h3 class="null"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; Text blurb here </h3>
<h3 class="null"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; Text blurb here</h3>
<h3 class="null"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; Text blurb here</h3>
<h3 class="null"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; Text blurb here</h3>
<h3 class="null"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; Text blurb here </h3>

<hr>
<h3> <strong> Some text here as well  </strong>
<h4> some more text here too </h4><br>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

How can I get the video not to stretch in the height.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just make the width and the height in the iframe = 100% to fill the bootstrap div

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/97pd8Lsh/

Comment: Thanks Peavey, where should I do that?

Comment: Thanks, I did that but still the same result :(

Comment: Did you check the jsfiddle? It sits next to the text on my screen and it doesn't expand the height abnoxiously

Comment: Yes I can see there.. but i think something wrong with my bootstrap settings!

Comment: Is there some more code above/below that is maybe interfering? Maybe try wrapping this section in a '<div class="row"></div>'?